# operator+ not returning full object?

Tags: c++

We're given this header file which requires us to overload the `=` and `+` operators so we can do `i3 = i1 + i2`.

For some reason, my `+` operator isn't returning a full object... It returns the strings just fine, but the integers are returning -858993460. Which is strange considering I assigned them a value.

Here is my `+` operator:

```
Image Image::operator+(Image const& image)
{
    return image;
}
```

In my `=` operator, which is where the value gets passed to, it displays the `int`s incorrectly:

```
const Image& Image::operator=(Image const& image)
{
    cout << image.filename << endl; // Displays correctly
    cout << "image x: " << image.size_x << ": " << image.get_size_x() << endl; // Displays incorrectly (-int)
```

Here I was working on a new object, but it wasn't working so I just simply passed an object I knew had values assigned and it still faces the uninit int problem. Regardless of which object I pass, I face the same issues. Strings are ok, but the ints seem to not be passed correctly

Comment: Show your copy constructor, which is being used by your `return` statement.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly your copy constructor

Comment: Thank you for stating it is homework.  I think more folks will help

Comment: Curious, what happens if you don't involve your operator+() method at all, dumping the value of directly with code? Isolate if it's really the operator, the class, or if you need to do something special with cout due to the member type.

Comment: A bit more const correctness couldn't hurt but most likely your copy constructor is malformed. Note there is no assignment in your assignment operator that I can see either just some `cout` statements.

Comment: It turned out to be my copy constructor after all. I feel rather silly now. Can't believe I missed it :\.  Thanks for all the help guys! (I can't answer my own question until 8 hours after I ask it due to my reputation :< ).

And yes, my = operator wasn't the culprit of the issue, I just wanted to show the prototype and how I knew it was breaking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turned out it WAS my copy constructor. I feel very silly now.

All I had to do was assign a default value in my operator that took an Image as a parameter.

ie:

```
Image::Image( Image & const img )
{
     this->size_x = img.get_size_x();
}
```

Comment: Note that you can also use something called the `ctor-initializer` like this: `Image::Image(Image & const img) : size_x(img.get_size_x()) {}` to initialize the `size_x` member.

Comment: although an even better option would be to just let the compiler create the default copy constructor. A copy constructor that copies an integer is pretty useless.

Comment: right, in our homework we had to do other operations than this, but that was the root of my issues.